# Disallow user from entering, listing specific folders

Tags: permissions, etc, account-restrictions

I have a question about, how can I restrict a standard user from entering the `/etc` folder? My goal is to have a user with bash, who can enter the `/var/www/html` folder and its own home folder but nothing else.

Comment: i don't think that you can forbid entering /etc, most of the configuration files are kept there. user can enter and read but nor write.

Comment: That is my problem, that they can read. :(

Comment: You can change permissions with `chmod` and restrict read permission, but I can't tell you, what it happens with system.

Comment: You can assign an ACL entry to `/etc` for the user under consideration, but a few things will break for sure. Your question seems to be the typical XY problem (e.g. see http://xyproblem.info/) - what is it that you _actually_ want?

Comment: Well I've sorted it out a completely different way. The main goal wa to have a user who can execute PHP commands and see all the files for websites and have bash as well in case we have to execute the PHP command manually. Anything else should have been restricted for it. I've solved it by creating a standard user who is allowed to do everything we wanted, put ACLs on my website folders so the group is always staing nginx, added the user to nginx group and enhanced the security by using SSH keys and denied password authentication (+  a few other things)